# layout on android studio preview doesn't look the same when running the app on the phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

im developing an android app on android studio, when i run my app the layout looks a bit different from the preview as well as on other phones,
for example: the buttons are in different order (from right to left instead from left to right) or other changes similar to this.
as well as on some phones the layout doesn't fit perfectly on the screen for example: the buttons on the sides of the screen appear to be cut out.
how can i fix it so the app will look the same with every phone and not only some of them?

Answer (score 2):

About the Right-to-left/ Left-to-right, you can choose the globe icon in the preview options bar frame and then choose `Preview Right-to-Left Layout` option. This will "fix" the buttons order in preview.

Comment: thank but why is it happening, can i do anything so it will look the same on the phone as it looks on the preview?

Comment: It's happening because the default settings of Android Studio are English, and your phone (I guess) are in Right-to-left Language (Hebrew for example).

Answer (score 0):

About the buttons that appear to be cut out - make sure you use dp units instead of pixels. You can read more about it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check if you have used the constraints on your components properly. Usually that's what makes the layout messy after running the app on your phone/emulator, even tho it looks perfect on your XML file.

Comment: When you get the reputation for comments, this should be one.